# Implement multiple authorization in .net 6 web API

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, .net-6.0, auth0, webapi

I have auth0 authentication implemented for my webAPIs. But now due to some requirement change few of APIs need to be authorized with another scheme. So I need below specified different authorization schemes to authorize my API

1. Auth0 scheme (already authorizing api's)
2. Azure AD B2C

I have implemented Azure AD B2C and which is working fine when used alone but when I am trying to add it enable it with a previous scheme it is causing issues.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSecurityPolicy(this IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager config)
        {
            const string ClientPortalScheme = "ClientPortalBearerScheme";
            //from https://auth0.com/blog/securing-aspnet-minimal-webapis-with-auth0/
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = config["AuthenticationSettings:Domain"];
                options.Audience = config["AuthenticationSettings:Audience"];
            }).AddJwtBearer(ClientPortalScheme, ClientPortalScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = config["AzureADB2CSettings:Domain"];
                options.Audience = config["AzureADB2CSettings:Tenant"];
            });
            //services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(config, "AzureADB2CSettings");

            //By default, require an authenticated user
            //Only one JWT bearer authentication is registered with the default authentication scheme JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.
            //Additional authentication has to be registered with a unique authentication scheme.
            //see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
             {
                 var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                     JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                     ClientPortalScheme);
                 defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
                     defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                 options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
             });

            return services;
        }
```

This is how my code looks like.
Issue is when I am calling my endpoint it says

```
Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://mydomain.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://mydomain.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

Please let me know if any information is required int this regard

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment.***

It occurs when app config is not receiving  OpenIDmeta data properly

The issue was due to TLS configuration in my case as  TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.0 are depreciated.

[image]

Please make sure to set ***TLS to 1.2*** or greater.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

***Startup.cs***

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
           ......
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;;
               ....
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
          ....

}
```

[image]

Please make sure  your backend API refers to  ***`/.well-known/openid-configuration`***
Or check this way.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        MetadataAddress = "http[s]://{IdentityServer}/.well-known/openid-configuration"
        ...
    });
```

- In AzureAdB2c make sure to set the Authority or (Domain and instance ) property correctly .
- Authority being the combination of Instance and domain
  Appsettings.json
  **Authority :** `https://[yourb2ctenant}.b2clogin.com/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0`

Also see if ***Instance*** can be `https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/tfp/`
***Domain*** : `<b2ctenant>.onmicrosoft.com`

Then the authentication can be carried on successfully: